# GraqlSemanticException-label 'database' not found. Please check server logs for the stack trace

Tags: vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

So I was trying to get [Biograkn](https://github.com/graknlabs/biograkn) usecase for BLAST working , following the steps as per [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vZc5fc6zmYI&list=PLtEF8_xCPklaTR4RaB3ng9V3Ov7n980cQ&index=2) video series. I was able to load the schema , but after that we need to execute `python migrate.py` to load data into it. I executed the command and i am getting the following error traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aditya/anaconda3/envs/RD/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grakn/service/Session/TransactionService.py", line 161, in send
    response = next(self._response_iterator)
  File "/home/aditya/anaconda3/envs/RD/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 364, in __next__
    return self._next()
  File "/home/aditya/anaconda3/envs/RD/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 358, in _next
    raise self
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT
    details = "GraqlSemanticException-label 'database' not found. Please check server logs for the stack trace."
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1582269484.666990683","description":"Error received from peer","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1017,"grpc_message":"GraqlSemanticException-label 'database' not found. Please check server logs for the stack trace.","grpc_status":3}"
>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "migrate.py", line 92, in <module>
    init(data_path="uniprot-asthma-proteins.fasta")
  File "migrate.py", line 23, in init
    session, q_get_database, q_insert_database, "$db"
  File "/home/aditya/Projects/RD/biograkn/blast/util.py", line 14, in insert_if_non_existent
    found_list = list(read_transaction.query(get_query))
  File "/home/aditya/anaconda3/envs/RD/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grakn/client.py", line 131, in query
    return self._tx_service.query(query, infer)
  File "/home/aditya/anaconda3/envs/RD/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grakn/service/Session/TransactionService.py", line 49, in query
    response = self._communicator.send(request)
  File "/home/aditya/anaconda3/envs/RD/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grakn/service/Session/TransactionService.py", line 165, in send
    raise GraknError("Server/network error: {0}\n\n generated from request: {1}".format(e, request))
grakn.exception.GraknError.GraknError: Server/network error: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT
    details = "GraqlSemanticException-label 'database' not found. Please check server logs for the stack trace."
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1582269484.666990683","description":"Error received from peer","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1017,"grpc_message":"GraqlSemanticException-label 'database' not found. Please check server logs for the stack trace.","grpc_status":3}"
>

 generated from request: query_req {
  query: "match $db isa database, has name \"uniprot\"; get $db;"
}
```

now this is not understandable why loading is not possible. Hence requesting for assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to already be a problem with the schema, since graql is trying to look for the label "database" but cannot find it.

You can check your schema using workbase:
 1. connect to your local server (localhost:48555)
 2. select your keyspace ("proteins")
 3. click on the hierarchy symbol on the top left next to the grakn logo

If the schema is present, it will be visualized automatically.